# Do DynamoDB secondary indexes contain actual table rows?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In the SQL world when you create a non clustered index it creates a separate data structure that allows you to find pointers to table rows based on a key that is not the primary key of the table.

From the DynamoDB docs it seems as though creating a secondary index creates a separate data structure that holds a copy of the actual table rows, not just a pointer to those rows.

Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's partially correct - for a global secondary index, it will definitely create a second table and update that asynchronously based on the changes in the primary table. That's why you can only do eventually consistent reads on this index.

For local secondary indexes it's most likely the same table.

There is a talk from re:invent 2018, where they explain the underlying data structures, which I can highly recommend:

[AWS re:Invent 2018: Amazon DynamoDB Under the Hood: How We Built a Hyper-Scale Database (DAT321)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvBR71D0nAQ)

Comment: Ah right - without the partition key copying that actual table rows makes sense so you can avoid jumping around partitions. But for local indexes pointers would work just fine. Thanks for the vid recommendation, I'll take a look.

Comment: Also note that the ROWS in a GSI will contain only what you've [projected](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Projections).  `KEYS_ONLY` , `INCLUDE`, or `ALL`

Comment: Just read that with an LSI you actually have the choice of whether or not to copy the table rows - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.Projections.